# measuring only CPU time (not clock time) in python

Tags: python, time, benchmarking, cpu-usage

I would like to compare two scripts I wrote in order to know which one is more efficient. Each script takes a while (several hours), and I use my computer in the meantime for other tasks. How can I measure the pure CPU time each script needs to perform the task in order to have a fair benchmark? Using the clock() and time() (including process_time()) yields different results, depends on whether the computer CPU is busy or idle. I'd like to have a fixed value for a specific task on a specific machine and environment.

Comment: Please show us what have you tried so far, so we can give better solution or some ideas for your solution.

Comment: What OS are you working with?

Comment: Leave the computer alone and do not perform other tasks in the meantime.

Comment: Following the [documents](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.clock) `time.clock()` is the one to use. But if you search here it's full of questions about this.

Comment: The best estimate you can get is from [`time.process_time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.process_time).

Comment: @toti08 Why are you linking to the Python 2 docs? There have been quite a few improvements and additions to the `time` module since then.

Comment: @PM 2Ring sorry, since he didn't specified I assumed he was working with python 2.

Comment: @toti08 No worries. Python 3 is almost 10 years old, and Python 2 will reach its official End of Life sometime in 2020. Almost nobody should be writing new code in Python 2 any more, only doing repairs to legacy systems. And people learning Python now should _definitely_ avoid Python 2 until they've gained some expertise in Python 3. That way they won't have to un-learn various bad habits. ;)

Comment: I use Windows OS and Python 3. I tried using time(), clock() anf process_time(), all three methods showed significant bias between idle computer and a busy one.

Comment: 1) there are no fair benchmarks, all are bogus, to easy to manipulate.  2) what is your definition of CPU time?  You want to measure the instruction count of the VM executing the python?  fetches?  memory accesses?  what is the measurement you think will determine performance or efficiency?  3) what else is going on that a wall clock time wont work?  do you have idle periods in the code?

Comment: I would like to count the performing time of each script as if it would have been running on a computer with no other process interfering. I could do this by runing each script alone and not use my computer to any other use in the meantime, but these are heavy scripts (a day or two for a task) and I really need my computer for other uses. I tried using clock() but I found major differences (up to 100%) between performance alone and performance on a busy computer.